# Java jTabPanel, handle with specific tab

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane, changelistener

I create a jTabPanl with 3 tab: add, update, remove for example. It can be if I click on each tab, it show index tab such as:

- click on Add tab, it do `System.out.println("clicking tab 0")`
- click on Update tab, it do `System.out.println("clicking tab 1")`
- click on Delete tab, it do `System.out.println("clicking tab 3")`
  Can anyone help me?

Finally, I do it:

```
ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        jTabbedPane1 = (JTabbedPane) e.getSource();
        int index = jTabbedPane1.getSelectedIndex();
            System.out.println("click tab " + index);
    }
};

jTabbedPane1.addChangeListener(changeListener);
```

Comment: `I create a jTabPanl` - I assume you mean JTabbedPane. Use proper class names so we don't have to guess what you are talking about.

Comment: I think that when I ask a question I should make it simple as possible. This is demo. Anyway, thank for your opinion

Comment: *"thank for your opinion"*  That 'opinion', or as I would describe it 'excellent advice', is not just thought by the person that said it.  But I'll go further.  If you could not be bothered typing the name correctly or copy/pasting it, please stop wasting our time.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson. Please don't take it a wrong way. All I did is find for a help. I don't know too much. And I really don't know my question is a little bit difficult to guess. At first, I think it must be more complex also.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `ChangeListener` to the JTabbedPane. When the listener fires you will need to get the currently selected tab from the JTabbedPane and then do your processing.

Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a Change Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/changelistener.html) for basic information on change listeners.